# Random method tic tac toe android

Tags: java, android, tic-tac-toe

I am developing a tic tac toe game for android. The user will play against the computer. I am all most done with the game but just stuck at this one last problem. I tried a lot but couldn't find a proper random method to select a random square which is empty.
This is the way i have declared my 9 buttons.

```
    btn00 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    btn20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    btn21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    btn22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you want the computer player to play by the game logic rather than select an empty square at random?

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche I am just a 14 year old kid. i have already programmed the logic but for the first move i want the computer to choose a random sqaure. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Put your buttons into a list, generate a random number, and get the selected number's button from the list.

Comment: You simply remove that button from the list - watch out for the random generator too to avoid IndexOutOfBounds exceptions!

Answer (score 1):

to avoid selecting a button that has been already selected u can form an array of size 9, pick a random number and remove it. here's an example:`

```
/**
 * RandomArray is a data structure similiar to a set, which removes a random number one at a time and decreases the size of the set by one.
 */
public class RandomArray {
    int size;
    int[] array;

/**
 * The only constructor for this class. assigns numbers from 1 to m in the 0 to m-1 cells respectively. 
 * @param size holds the value of m - meaning, the method will generate a number for each movie.
 */
public RandomArray(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
}

/**
 * remove removes a number randomly and returns it.
 * with each removal the number in the last cell replaces the removed number and size is decreased by one.
 * @return a random number represents a movie that hasn't been played yet.
 */
public int remove() {
    int ans = -1;
    if (size > 0) {
        // generating a random number from 0 to the last cell. 
        int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*size);
        ans = array[randomNum];
        // last number replaces the number to be removed.
        array[randomNum] = array[size-1];
        size--;
    }
    return ans;
}
}
```

EDIT: i forgot to mention: put all ur buttons in an array. that way the number generated is the array cell

`

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to separate the view from the state.

```
int[] state = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // int[9] 
Button[] buttons = new Button[] { 
   (Button) findViewById(R.id.button),
   (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2),
   (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3),
   ...
}
```

Then try to find an empty cell using the state:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.nextInt(state.length);
while(state[index] != 0) {
    index = rnd.nextInt(state.length);
}
```

Set the state:

```
state[index] = 1;
```

Then update your button:

```
Button b = buttons[index];
b.set....();
...
```

The same applies to your buttons when the user clicks them, use this function in onClick() to determine the index:

```
int getIndex(Button b) {
   for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      if(buttons[i].equals(b)) {
         return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```